# Pre-Request Script scopes in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have collection named "Auth" with pre-request script where I define JavaScript variable "token", and some JavaScript general functions, which I want to use in my inner pre-request scripts.

Within "Auth" collection I have folder name "Tests" with own pre-request script. I expected both scripts to be merged but when I try to use "token" JavaScript variable from "Auth" collection I get an error:

> ReferenceError: currentAccessToken is not defined

How to access JavaScript variables (and JavaScript functions) from collection pre-request script in inner folder pre-request script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman has different variable scopes, which you would need to use, eg:

```
pm.globals.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
pm.globals.get("variable_key");

pm.collectionVariables.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_key");

pm.environment.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
pm.environment.get("variable_key");
```

Please check out [Using variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) for more details.

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution for variables but how about the JavaScript function which I want to reuse at my inner pre-request script (I edit my question with additional JavaScript mentions)? Are you sure that it is the only options, I try to find solution where pre-request script will be merged, and it would be the best for me.

Comment: Afaik, the only way to reuse functions is to store them in a postman variable, than use eval(). Not very nice, I know.

Comment: I agree that it's not very nice, I will wait for a few more days and if there will be not other solutions then I will accept this answer.